# sizeof an inline struct declaration

Tags: c++, c, memory

If there's a structure with a pointer to a struct declared within it, how do you determine the size of the sub-struct?

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  int member;
  struct subStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
  } *subStruct_t;
} myStruct_t;
```

How do you allocate space for the `subStruct_t` pointer? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
myStruct_t M;
M.subStruct_t = calloc(1,sizeof(myStruct_t.subStruct_t);
```

but it obviously doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't agree with the retagging. There are C answers to this question and C++ ones.

Comment: Neither do I.  If the intent is to get a clear, single-purpose question, then it should first be established with the OP *which* language he wants the answer for.

Comment: @DeadMG, please comment properly on the retagging, this is not a valid edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
M.subStruct_t = calloc(1,sizeof(*M.subStruct_t));
```

Note: allocate for the size of the structure, not for the pointer

Comment: Alternately, `M.subStruct_t = malloc(sizeof *M.subStruct_t);`.

Answer (score 4):

In C, inner structs get placed in the global namespace, so you can simply use `sizeof(struct subStruct)`.  In C++, you have to use the scope resolution operator `::`, so you would instead say `sizeof(myStruct::subStruct)`.

You can also just use the name of the dereferenced variable -- the operands to `sizeof` are not evaluated -- so `sizeof(*M.subStruct_t)` would also work.

One piece of advice: do not name your struct member with the `_t` suffix.  The `_t` suffix should be used for *types*, not for variables/members.  Furthermore, POSIX reserves all identifiers with the `_t` suffix (see [section 2.2.2 of the POSIX.1-2008 spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02)), so you should not name your own types with `_t`.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using c++, you should not use the typedef-syntax, but more cleanly:

```
struct myStruct_t {
  int member;
  struct subStruct_t {
    int a;
    int b;
  };

  subStruct_t* subStruct;
};
```

then you can get the size with:

```
sizeof(myStruct_t::subStruct_t);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++

```
myStruct_t M;
M.subStruct_t = (myStruct_t::subStruct*)calloc(1,sizeof(myStruct_t::subStruct));
```

I really wouldn't name variables or data members as subStruct_t, the _t convention is used for types.

Answer (score 0):

One technique that's sometimes useful (e.g. in macros that take the type as an argument):

```
sizeof(*((struct myStruct *)0)->subStruct_t);
```

I'm not 100% sure but I believe this is legal since the operand of `sizeof` is not actually evaluated.